# How can I force a TextBox's DataSource to update after a change in value through code?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, controls, datasource

I am binding a `TextBox`'s `text` property to a field value in a `DataTable` as such:

```
With control.Item_Full_Description
     .DataBindings.Add("Text", mdtItemMstr, "Item_Full_Description", True)
End With
```

When I make changes to the `TextBox` manually they are detected and updated in the data source, thus a save to the database is accurate. If I make the change behind the scenes, however, the data source is not updated and a save to the database results in the old value being saved back. Here is how I am updating the `TextBox` in the code:

```
Item_Full_Description.Text = _mItem_mstr_c + " - " + Item_Description.Text + " - " + Unit_of_Measurement_UOM.Text
```

I am clearly missing a fundamental step to have this change reflected in the data source, however a search online is not proving to be useful. Maybe I am just uncertain of what to search so any advice or even guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the control from code you need to force the binding source to update.

Look into the BindingContext class...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
BindingContext([data source]).EndCurrentEdit()
```

Comment: Great, thank you. A follow up question for you - is it safe to call this in a text changed event over and over before a single save? It seems like it should only be called once before accepting changes however I am not sure.

Comment: Ideally you would only want to call this once after all changes have been made to prevent any conflicts and for performance reasons.